# How exactly does oil drying work (specifically with the case of linoleum)?

Tags: fats

I understand that it’s a form of autoxidation, and so with the presence of oxygen, the oxygen reacts with a double bond of the unsaturated fat to create a hydro peroxide, however I don’t really understand the processes that follow and why they happen.

Comment: Readily found on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drying_oil